# Two non-negative integers are chosen at random, then the probability that the sum of their squares is divisible by 5 is?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I saw answer to a similar question but I want mathematical answer not just a view-able thingy.

what I did was same as in that question but that got too long, I tried it for first 10 numbers, but the came out a little wrong, please help me.

Regards
Gaurav

Answer (score 4):

You can't choose two non-negative integers "at random", but presumably the question is really asking about the limit as $N \to \infty$ of the case where the integers are chosen uniformly from $\{0, \ldots, N\}^2$.

Hint: it is enough to consider $(x,y) \in \{0,\ldots,4\}^2$.

Comment: can you explain  a little more, I had left probability chapter around 6 months back

Comment: Without knowing what you tried yourself, and where you're stuck, we really can't help you effectively.